# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<nt>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I see an information log in my console that looks like an error. It is printed from "art", which is generally associated to memory but I need help understanding what it means. The class in question is my MapFragment class. The MapFragment is a custom class I created that extends SupportMapFragment so that I can override touch events. Is this class causing this issue, and how can I resolve?

Here is my MapFragment class

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    private TouchableWrapper mTouchView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View originalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
        mTouchView.addView(originalContentView);
        return mTouchView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return mTouchView;
    }

    /**
     * MapOnTouchListener callback
     *
     * @param listener
     */
    public void setMapTouchListener(TouchableWrapper.MapOnTouchListener listener) {
        mTouchView.setMapOnTouchListener(listener);
    }
```

The error I am receiving is,

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<nt>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/chimera/Fragment;
     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile) (DexFile.java:-2)
     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:299)
    at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:292)
     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(java.lang.String, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:418)
     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
     at java.lang.Class bzi.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (:com.google.android.gms:28)
     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ez com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fi.a(android.content.Context, com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.as, com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fp, java.lang.String, boolean) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:177)
     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions, boolean, java.lang.String, com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.e, android.app.Activity) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:347)
     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions, boolean, com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.e, android.app.Activity) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:320)
     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bq com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cp.a(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
     at un com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.co.a(un, un, android.os.Bundle) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:139)
     at boolean com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.w.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:107)
     at boolean android.os.Binder.transact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (Binder.java:507)
     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper, android.os.Bundle) ((null):-1)
     at android.view.View com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) ((null):-1)
     at void com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.LifecycleDelegate) ((null):-1)
     at void com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(android.os.Bundle, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$zza) ((null):-1)
     at android.view.View com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) ((null):-1)
     at android.view.View com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) ((null):-1)
     at android.view.View android.rider.flex.udi.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (MapFragment.java:19)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (Fragment.java:2192)
     at void android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(android.support.v4.app.Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) (FragmentManager.java:1255)
     at void android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) (FragmentManager.java:1472)
     at void android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment, boolean) (FragmentManager.java:1691)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (FragmentManager.java:3440)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (FragmentController.java:120)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (FragmentActivity.java:378)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (FragmentActivity.java:79)
     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:784)
     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.content.Context, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:1011)
     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:861)
     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
     at void android.rider.flex.udi.activity.MapActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MapActivity.java:196)
     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.chimera.Fragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000024/DynamiteModulesB_GmsCore_prodmnc_alldpi_release.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000024/n/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
     at java.lang.Class bzi.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (:com.google.android.gms:34)
     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile) (DexFile.java:-2)
     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:299)
     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:292)
     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(java.lang.String, java.util.List) (DexPathList.java:418)
     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
     at java.lang.Class bzi.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (:com.google.android.gms:28)
     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ez com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fi.a(android.content.Context, com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.as, com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fp, java.lang.String, boolean) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:177)
     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions, boolean, java.lang.String, com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.e, android.app.Activity) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:347)
     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.az.a(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions, boolean, com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.e, android.app.Activity) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:320)
     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bq com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cp.a(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
     at un com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.co.a(un, un, android.os.Bundle) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:139)
     at boolean com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.w.onTransact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:107)
     at boolean android.os.Binder.transact(int, android.os.Parcel, android.os.Parcel, int) (Binder.java:507)
     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.IObjectWrapper, android.os.Bundle) ((null):-1)
     at android.view.View com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) ((null):-1)
     at void com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(com.google.android.gms.dynamic.LifecycleDelegate) ((null):-1)
     at void com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(android.os.Bundle, com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$zza) ((null):-1)
     at android.view.View com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) ((null):-1)
     at android.view.View com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) ((null):-1)
     at android.view.View android.rider.flex.udi.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (MapFragment.java:19)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle) (Fragment.java:2192)
     at void android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(android.support.v4.app.Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) (FragmentManager.java:1255)
     at void android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(android.support.v4.app.Fragment) (FragmentManager.java:1472)
     at void android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment, boolean) (FragmentManager.java:1691)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (FragmentManager.java:3440)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (FragmentController.java:120)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (FragmentActivity.java:378)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
     at android.view.View android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (FragmentActivity.java:79)
     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:784)
     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:734)
     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:865)
     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.content.Context, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:1011)
     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:861)
     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:828)
     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:525)
     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:427)
     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:378)
     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
     at void android.rider.flex.udi.activity.MapActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MapActivity.java:196)
     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6942)
     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1126)
     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2880)
     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2988)
     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1631)
     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6682)
     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Comment: did you resolved the issue?

Answer (score -13, accepted):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError indicates, that something was found at compiletime but not at runtime. Maybe you just have to add it to the Classpath.

Right click on your project and select -> Compile Module, and then re-start the project and it should work again.

Comment: I can't find **Compile Module**, please write your solution steps or post an image that shows the steps of the solution

Comment: @portfoliobuilder how did you do these steps?

Comment: Yeah I have the same question, cant find this option anymore.

Comment: @Baxtex the solution is old now. Do the following. First clean project and see if that resolves your issue. Second, in your xml where you reference the MapFragment, don't use "class". Use "name". For example, android:name="<your package>.MapFragment". MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment. These steps removed the error for me

Comment: I am getting similar issue while using LocationListener. Where Location code is in a .jar which is imported as a jar dependency in another project. I need help

Answer (score 7):

I would try a clean and reset-cache.

File -> Invalidate Cache and restart

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and crash. I tried Invalidate Cache and restart and also tried clearing my app data on the emulator. The key to fixing it was **wiping the entire emulator's os** and then the error and crash went away. It was never an issue on a real device.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-check this line

```
View originalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 1):

Clean Project and Run app again worked for me.

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was having errors in design view. I overlooked those errors and ran the program, I got above exceptions.

However, When I went to design view. I saw a red error symbol at right top. I clicked at the symbol and got error details.

Error details could be different for you, but for me column index of one button was out of the range of grid column number.

I re-ran after fixing those errors. Worked for me.