# What is 'android.webkit.SafeBrowsingResponse' error?

Tags: android, android-webview

I use webview in my activity.

I don't know when, but I get the following error message.

Even if I search for this, I don't have much information.

Although it is not a serious error, I would like to fix it so that I do not receive such a message.

If anyone knows how to fix it, I would like to get some advice.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.SafeBrowsingResponse" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.webview-8CSSo1rZm_xmerbnZrD5xA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.google.android.webview-8CSSo1rZm_xmerbnZrD5xA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.google.android.webview-8CSSo1rZm_xmerbnZrD5xA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:42)
        at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:651)
        at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:581)
        at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:564)
        at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:551)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at void android.support.v7.app.l.b(int) (SourceFile:287)
        at void android.support.v7.app.e.setContentView(int) (SourceFile:139)
        at void bateaux.spt.coolnjoy.Activity.ArticleActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (SourceFile:109)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7174)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2910)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6940)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:327)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
I/zygote64: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter$3>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/SafeBrowsingResponse;
        at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:42)
        at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:651)
        at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:581)
        at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:564)
        at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:551)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at void android.support.v7.app.l.b(int) (SourceFile:287)
        at void android.support.v7.app.e.setContentView(int) (SourceFile:139)
        at void bateaux.spt.coolnjoy.Activity.ArticleActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (SourceFile:109)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7174)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2910)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6940)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:327)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: This class is supported from API level 27 (Android 8.1). https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/SafeBrowsingResponse.html Maybe update Chrome will help?

Comment: @bjc before wrote this question, i saw this doc. but i couldnt understand why classnotfoundexception was thrown. i'm not having any problem from this, just want to know why.

Comment: Do you use API level 27 (Android 8.1) for both your developing and running environment?

Comment: @bjc min=21, target=27, compile=27.

Comment: What is the running environment? Do the solutions list in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922288/ help?

Comment: @bjc i've using samsung note8, galaxy s4, emulator momo. i can't remember where it happened over time. but this class is in API level 27. i think it caused in samsung note8.

Comment: So I guess this problem is caused by the target API version is higher than the running environment. Set the target version to less than 27 should solve it.

Comment: @bjc hmm...i think it can be solution. and...just...i dont know definite cause. i'll find another solution from your guess. thnak you

Comment: Did you find a solution ?I am also seeing same error

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar No, I didn't find a solution. I didn't have time to find a solution. To avoid errors, we need to lower the version of the target.

Comment: @01hanst ok thanks buddy

Answer (score 2):

Solution for the problem is:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    view.getSettings().setSafeBrowsingEnabled(false);
}

WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I think, this code is similar work to set targetSDK version to low.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for compile SDK 28, target SDK 28, and min SDK 24.

Comment: The code actually works and we have it working in production! In API 28 and below also! The SDK doesn't actually work! And you can make the report to the Android Developers! Since they have managed to do something completely bad once again. Cheers

Comment: How could it work?According to the log this error occurs inside of the constructor of super class.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin. This might be useful for some one else

```
settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    settings.safeBrowsingEnabled = true
}
```