# My app stopped when adding a RecyclerView Layoutmanager

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, classnotfoundexception

I'm setting up an app for a Firebase Realtime Database. For this, I want to give out the data in a vertical Layout. The Problem is that the app stopped when I add the LinearLayoutManager.

This is the Tutorial I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71H9-MRXYOE

I already tried to add the LinearLayoutManager in different ways but none of them worked

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
              RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

I am really new to programming with android and don't understand much about error codes.

```
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.example.firebasetest.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:34)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6679)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],na
        at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
        at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(android.view.View, androidx.core.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (ViewCompat.java:2203)
        at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:637)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
        at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at void com.example.firebasetest.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:34)
        at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6679)
        at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
        at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
        at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
I/ViewConfigCompat: Could not find method getScaledScrollFactor() on ViewConfiguration
```

This is my layout

````
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_title"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_content"
        android:hint="Content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_post"
        android:text="POST"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>```
````

Comment: Please clean the project and try again

Comment: Are you sure this error is related to linearlayoutmanager? Look at your logcat carefully. Your error is this :     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file ....

Comment: And you can try this: recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this); -- Recyclerview.Vertical is defaul value. You don't need to initialize it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<nt>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922288/rejecting-re-init-on-previously-failed-class-java-lang-classnt-java-lang-nocl)

Comment: what is in the line 34 of your MainActivity?

Comment: @payam in line 34 is this "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);"

Comment: @StefanMueller can you attach your layout?

Comment: @payam I attached it

Comment: It worked for me without any adapter. The problem is probably from item layout in tour adapter or your adapter. so first comment ` recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` and then run your app. Then change your items layout and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: @payam Now the app will start, but I don't see the content on display

Comment: yes because the adapter and the layout you set there is your problem. You may used a vector in your imageview or something like this.

Comment: @payam ok I give up. I just started to program and only wanted to follow a tutorial. I don't have the knowledge to understand what you mean, but thank you a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter --- would have incorrectly overridden the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060702/before-android-4-1-method-android-graphics-porterduffcolorfilter-would-have)

Answer (score 0):

- May be this will help

1] vertical scrolling `RecyclerView` can be achieved with:-

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

2] Error in `logcat` shows like this:-

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/base.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.example.firebasetest-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],na

Which basically can be solved by (Majorly focus on Fire base related dependencies)

- clean up your project dependencies
- Update any dependencies if    needed to latest version .

and at last

3] Clean up your project , rebuild and run.

Comment: This, unfortunately, didn't solve the Problem. I updated all dependencies and edited the code as you wrote in 1]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in LayoutManager.Problem lays is in this error message:

```
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

And this has been already answered look at this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45191408/11555781

Comment: Ok I understand, but which method names should I change

Comment: Please try to clean project and rebuild and try again.If that is not working go through your drawables ,check if there is any .svg they can also contain this error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue cropped up for me when I switched a Gallery to a RecyclerView.
I was able to resolve it by adding the below dependency to my build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.5.0-alpha01'
```